# ignore modifications of certain files in working copy of svn repo without multiple commits of directory properties

Tags: svn, svnignore

My working copy of svn repo has the following status:

```
svn st --no-ignore
 M .
I ignored_1.txt
I ignored_2.txt
 M images
I images/ignored_1.txt
I images/ignored_2.txt
M  images/summer/_01_.png
M  videos/summer/_01_.mp4
M  videos/wanna_ignore.txt
```

I would like in my local(!) copy to ignore `images/summer/_01_.png`, `videos/summer/_01_.mp4`, and `videos/wanna_ignore.txt`. Setting `svn:ignore` properties for `images/summer` and `videos` is an option which I don't want as after `svn st` I would see too many (4) modified directories and that's distracting.

I am looking for a more general and "clean" solution for this.
One such could have been (but it is not working) to add the following list of paths (with multiple levels below) to the current directory `svn propedit svn:ignore .`

```
ignored_1.txt
ignored_2.txt
images/ignored_1.txt
images/ignored_2.txt
images/summer/_01_.png
videos/summer/_01_.mp4
videos/wanna_ignore.txt
```

And see only one modified directory when checking the status.
I am searching for a solution for Unix system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global-ignores` configuration option in the `config` file. The file is in the `%APPDATA%\Subversion` directory on Windows. On Unix-like systems the file is in the `.subversion` directory in your user's home directory. Learn more in the [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/).

This approach helps you configure ignores without any commits to the repository.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. but this doesn't seem to work per repository but for all svn repositories. Globally ignoring files with its full name might cause issues across repsoitories.